# Does jQuery "sizeContent" affect css media queries?

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have the following jQuery on my website to make sure the height is always full-screen:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    sizeContent();
    $(window).resize(sizeContent);
});

 function sizeContent() {
    'use strict';
    var newHeight = $("html").height() + "px";
    $(".wrapper").css("min-height", newHeight); 
  }
```

This works great. However, when I try to add media queries to my css to change the size of the fonts in the document, it seems as if the jQuery code "blocks" the css from calculating the width of the screen.
Can this be an issue?
If yes, how can I solve it with the least amount of jQuery?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Here's the css:

```
    @media screen {

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    a {
            font-family: letter-gothic-std, monospace;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #6f97a7;
        }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    a {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

The size of the links does not change at all.

Comment: what media queries are you using?

Comment: how are you using the media queries in css, I tried your code and it works with and without media queries, could you post relevant css/html?

Comment: I edited my post and added the css.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the media queries order:

```
@media screen {

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    a {
        font-family: letter-gothic-std, monospace;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #6f97a7;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    a {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

`@media screen` was taking precedence over `@media (max-width: 768px)`.

`font-size: 2em;` was being cancelled by `font-size: 1.1em;`

try to always declare them from general to specific (large to small), let me know if it helps

Comment: I'm sorry, but it didn't help. I tried it again in different browsers and it behaved totally different. I have a picture integrated and in chrome it's responsive whereas in firefox it's not. This is not my first project but I've never experienced this behaviour before. I'm puzzled. Thank you for your advise nevertheless.

Comment: @Lisa-AndreaGlatz; well I tried my code in MF and it worked (links resizing ok); honestly not an expert but the code u posted should work across browsers, it's only when you try experimental features like, for instance, `box-shadow` or `linear-gradient` or `border-radius` (don't know if those are off the hook by now) that you should prefix them (`-moz-`, `-webkit-`, `-o-`, etc) according to the target browser's version. google a bit more and check if you are using something regarding responsiveness that might be causing different results in different browser and c if u can fix it with prefixes